# Remove Wi-Fi Networks

Tags: wireless, networking

How do I remove the following ghost networks? When I go to the "Edit Connections..." menu these are not listed there. Moreover, it says that Winnie-the-Pooh is disconnected and connected at the same time!

[image: networks listed in notification area drop down menu]
[image: networks listed in connection manager]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the connection in Netowrk Connections and pressing 'delete'?

Comment: @Wilf Those connections were "unlisted" in Network Connections and that was the problem actually. However, it is not a bug. Later I figured that out. Those were the Bluetooth Networks. So, I think in "Network Connections" there should be a category called "Bluetooth" apart from DSL, Ethernet and Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks gio900. But, I have figured it out now. Those were the bluetooth paired devices over which networking was allowed.

[image: bluetooth]

Comment: so... did you resolve? :)

Comment: @gio900 yes. But, I think there should be a Bluetooth category apart from DSL, Ethernet and Wi-Fi in the Network Connections.

Answer (score 0):

This probably varies by the version of NetworkManager, but there if you go to 'Network' settings, there should be a bit to forget connections:
[image: Open up Network settings, click 'History', select the Networks you want to remove and press 'Forget']

This should also be possible via 'Network Connections'
[image: Select the connections you want to remove, and 'Delete' them]